# Internet Explorer Input Field wont work after statuschange disable -> enable

Tags: jquery, html, internet-explorer, input

I am actually trying to fix some kind of annoing IE BUG.

I created a html form with a checkbox for policys and a submit button.
The Submit Button is disabled as long as the policy checkbox isnt "checked".
All this I done with jquery.

The strange thing is, that it all works great in chrome, ff and safari, but in IE after the button loses the "disable" status, it stops to work. It is still shown as a link, but when I click on it, nothing happens.

Here is my script that I use to disable and enable the button:

```
/* Webform/Newsletter Checkbox + Mailfield validation */

var mailCheckbox = $('#webform-component-e-mail #edit-submitted-e-mail-newsletter-selection div').size();
var copyCheckbox = $('.webform-client-form input#edit-submitted-email-abmeldung-1, .webform-client-form #webform-component-datenschutzbestimmungen input#edit-submitted-datenschutzbestimmungen-1').size();


if(mailCheckbox > 1) {
        var submitButton = $('.webform-client-form #edit-actions').html();
            $('.webform-client-form #edit-actions').html('<input disabled type="submit" class="form-submit-disabled" value="Bestellen" name="op" id="edit-submit">')
            $('body').mousemove(function() {
        if ($('#edit-submitted-e-mail-newsletter-selection .form-checkbox').is(':checked') && $('#webform-component-email-abmeldung .form-checkbox').is(':checked') && $('#webform-component-e-mail #edit-submitted-e-mail-newsletter-email-address').val() != "" ) {
            $('.node-webform .webform-client-form #edit-actions').html('<input type="submit" class="form-submit" name="op" value="Absenden" id="edit-submit">')
            $('.node-newsletter-anmeldung .webform-client-form #edit-actions').html('<input type="submit" class="form-submit" name="op" value="Bestellen" id="edit-submit">')
        }
        else {
            $('.node-webform .webform-client-form #edit-actions').html('<input disabled type="submit" class="form-submit-disabled" value="Absenden" name="op" id="edit-submit">')
            $('.node-newsletter-anmeldung .webform-client-form #edit-actions').html('<input disabled type="submit" class="form-submit-disabled" value="Bestellen" name="op" id="edit-submit">')             
        }
        });
}
else {
        var submitButton = $('.webform-client-form #edit-actions').html();
            $('.webform-client-form #edit-actions').html('<input disabled type="submit" class="form-submit-disabled" value="Bestellen" name="op" id="edit-submit">')
            $('body').mousemove(function() {
        if ($('#webform-component-email-abmeldung .form-checkbox, #webform-component-datenschutzbestimmungen .form-checkbox').is(':checked') && $('#webform-component-e-mail #edit-submitted-e-mail-newsletter-email-address, #webform-component-webform-kontakt-email #edit-submitted-webform-kontakt-email').val() != "") {
            $('.node-webform .webform-client-form #edit-actions').html('<input type="submit" class="form-submit" name="op" value="Absenden" id="edit-submit">')
            $('.node-newsletter-anmeldung .webform-client-form #edit-actions').html('<input type="submit" class="form-submit" name="op" value="Bestellen" id="edit-submit">')
        }
        else {
            $('.node-webform .webform-client-form #edit-actions').html('<input disabled type="submit" class="form-submit-disabled" value="Absenden" name="op" id="edit-submit">')
            $('.node-newsletter-anmeldung .webform-client-form #edit-actions').html('<input disabled type="submit" class="form-submit-disabled" value="Bestellen" name="op" id="edit-submit">')
        }
        });
}

$('body.node-type-newsletter-anmeldung #edit-submit').attr('value', 'Bestellen');
$('body.node-webform #edit-submit').attr('value', 'Absenden');
```

Any idea how to workaround this?

Comment: try to keep `alert("hello")` step by step in your code to track the error. (old, but works)

Answer (score 0):

I got it working by myself, for anyone else running in that problem, here is how i solved it:

```
/* Webform/Newsletter Checkbox + Mailfield validation */

    var mailCheckbox = $('#webform-component-e-mail #edit-submitted-e-mail-newsletter-selection div').size();
    var copyCheckbox = $('.webform-client-form input#edit-submitted-email-abmeldung-1, .webform-client-form #webform-component-datenschutzbestimmungen input#edit-submitted-datenschutzbestimmungen-1').size();

    $('.webform-client-form #edit-actions input').addClass('button_active');
    $('.webform-client-form #edit-actions').append('<div class="button_inactive"><input disabled type="submit" class="form-submit-disabled" value="Bestellen" name="op" id="edit-submit"></div>')

    if(mailCheckbox > 1) {
            var submitButton = $('.webform-client-form #edit-actions').html();
                $('.webform-client-form #edit-actions .button_active').css('display','none');
                $('body').mousemove(function() {
            if ($('#edit-submitted-e-mail-newsletter-selection .form-checkbox').is(':checked') && $('#webform-component-email-abmeldung .form-checkbox').is(':checked') && $('#webform-component-e-mail #edit-submitted-e-mail-newsletter-email-address').val() != "" ) {
                $('.node-webform .webform-client-form #edit-actions .button_active').css('display', 'block')
                $('.node-webform .webform-client-form #edit-actions .button_inactive').css('display', 'none')
                $('.node-newsletter-anmeldung .webform-client-form #edit-actions .button_active').css('display', 'block')
                $('.node-newsletter-anmeldung .webform-client-form #edit-actions .button_inactive').css('display', 'none')
            }
            else {
                $('.node-webform .webform-client-form #edit-actions .button_active').css('display','none');
                $('.node-webform .webform-client-form #edit-actions .button_inactive').css('display','block');
                $('.node-newsletter-anmeldung .webform-client-form #edit-actions .button_active').css('display','none');
                $('.node-newsletter-anmeldung .webform-client-form #edit-actions .button_inactive').css('display','block');
            }
            });
    }
    else {
            var submitButton = $('.webform-client-form #edit-actions').html();
                $('.webform-client-form #edit-actions .button_active').css('display','none');
                $('body').mousemove(function() {
            if ($('#webform-component-email-abmeldung .form-checkbox, #webform-component-datenschutzbestimmungen .form-checkbox').is(':checked') && $('#webform-component-e-mail #edit-submitted-e-mail-newsletter-email-address, #webform-component-webform-kontakt-email #edit-submitted-webform-kontakt-email').val() != "") {
                $('.node-webform .webform-client-form #edit-actions .button_active').css('display', 'block')
                $('.node-webform .webform-client-form #edit-actions .button_inactive').css('display', 'none')
                $('.node-newsletter-anmeldung .webform-client-form #edit-actions .button_active').css('display', 'block')
                $('.node-newsletter-anmeldung .webform-client-form #edit-actions .button_inactive').css('display', 'none')
            }
            else {
                $('.node-webform .webform-client-form #edit-actions .button_active').css('display','none');
                $('.node-webform .webform-client-form #edit-actions .button_inactive').css('display','block');
                $('.node-newsletter-anmeldung .webform-client-form #edit-actions .button_active').css('display','none');
                $('.node-newsletter-anmeldung .webform-client-form #edit-actions .button_inactive').css('display','block');
            }
            });
    }
```